# Легкий сдержанный шепот разбуди меня? - почему здесть неоднородные определения! спасибо

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

Легкий сдержанный шепот разбуди меня? - почему здесть неоднородные определения! спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Определения характеризуют предмет с разных сторон. Легкий шепот необязательно сдержанный. Он может быть взволнованный (несдержанный), быстрый, взахлеб и т.д.

Легкий - характеризует силу звука, тихий.

Сдержанный - характеризует темп речи, медленный, размеренный.

Тихий медленный шепот.

Но в авторском контексте эти определения могут стать однородными, если для автора легкий = сдержанный.

Comment: Интересно, в каком словаре написано, что "сдержанный - характеризует темп речи, медленный, размеренный". Сдержанный - от слова "сдерживать", но не скорость произношения, а силу звука. Поэтому в словарной статье и указано - "не обнаруживаемый, не проявляемый". Давайте пользоваться словарями, это просто, легко, доступно для каждого.

Comment: Это одна из интерпретаций контекстуального авторского значения. Где написано, что сдерживать можно только силу звука, а темп не бывает сдержанным/умеренным?  Вообще-то это музыкальный термин. И где написано, что легкий почти то же, что сдержанный, а тяжелый - это несдержанный? Авторская семантика словарями не ограничивается. Напр.: Тяжёлые, холодные лучи лежали на вершинах окрестных гор (Л.). Здесь "темные" подразумевает "тяжелые" и "холодные". В каком толковом словаре отражена их связь?

Comment: Шепот - это тихая, незвонкая речь, при которой звуки произносятся без участия голосовых связок. Понизить голос до шёпота.  Если еще уменьшить СИЛУ ЗВУКА то получится шёпот тихий, легкий, сдержанный, приглушенный, осторожный. Все эти слова - синонимы. Все остальные характеристики будут относиться к речи в общем плане: взволнованный шепот, тревожный шепот, медленный шепот.Что касается темпа, то в Нацкорпусе встретился только умеренный темп бега и умеренный темп стрельбы из пистолетов при полном отсутствии сдержанного темпа (видно, муз. термины характерны для спец. литературы).

Comment: София, вы сейчас спорите с Тургеневым и хотите, чтобы он поставил там запятую. А он не поставил, потому что для него "легкий" и "сдержанный" - разноплановые признаки. Я всего лишь попыталась понять почему. А на самом деле, может, для него "сдержанный" означало "стеариновая свечка". Душа автора - потемки:)
А шепот, кстати, бывает и громкий, как это ни парадоксально. Сдержанный - синоним умеренного, темп бывает умеренным, почему бы ему не быть сдержанным?

Comment: Всё-таки жаль, что нельзя ни с Александром Сергеичем, пи с Иваном Сергеичем поговорить о литературных делах. Например:а была ли запятая? Рукопись бы посмотреть или прижизненные издания. Да и полные синонимы встречаются редко, так что при желании "легкий и сдержанный" можно представить неоднородными, и запятую можно не ставить. Вот только хотелось бы  корректно и без особых фантазий объяснить ситуацию. Легкий шепот  - это, скорее, просто тихий, а сдержанный -  старающийся быть тихим, но не всегда равномерный и более эмоциональный.

Answer (score 2):

Легкий, сдержанный шепот.

Эти прилагательные, скорее, однородные, так как обозначают сходные признаки и раскрывают общую тему.

СДЕРЖАННЫЙ - не обнаруживаемый, не проявляемый в полной мере, в полную силу.

ЛЕГКИЙ - едва заметный, незначительный, небольшой, слабый (по величине, силе, степени проявления).

ДВА ВАРИАНТА

"Пока Ермолай жарил в золе картофель, я успел задремать… Легкий сдержанный шёпот разбудил меня" (Тургенев). "Отовсюду слышится легкий, сдержанный шепот, и тихий смех, и журчащий, отдаленный говор" (Н.П.Вагнер).

Другие шёпоты (с двумя определениями) отсутствуют, можно предложить  "легкий шепот" и "тихий шепот".

И еще интересный вариант: "И вот медленный шепот раздался под шлемом в его ушах. 
Лось сейчас же закрыл глаза. Снова ― повторился отдаленный тревожный, медленный шепот. Повторялось какое-то странное слово.(А. Н. Толстой. Аэлита).